# Can't copy file to the public storage

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin

I am trying to start an intent in order to open an image file, I download from the internet.

The image file I can download to the internal storage of the app, but I can't copy it to the public /Documents directory on my Android device, in order to start the intent.

This is how I copy the file

```
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (privatePath);
Java.IO.File docFolder = new Java.IO.File (global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/MyAppCache");
if (!docFolder.Exists ()) docFolder.Mkdir ();

Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File (docFolder.AbsolutePath, "cache.jpg");
file.CreateNewFile();

Java.IO.FileOutputStream fOut = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream (file);
fOut.Write (bytes);
fOut.Close ();

return file.AbsolutePath;
```

the returned path I use for

```
global::Android.Net.Uri uri = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse(FilePublisher.CopyToPublic());
StartActivity (new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri));
```

The result I get is

**`No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/MyAppCache/cache.jpg }`**

I checked the /storage folder on my device and there isn't even the MyAppCache folder in it.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The URI you are passing in the `Intent` doesn't contain the scheme. You can see this from the error:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/MyAppCache/cache.jpg }
```

The `"dat="` needs to start with `file:///`.